# Trying to split a string into 3 parts with Regex

Tags: java, regex

I need to split up a JSONPath path into 3 parts if it has a separator. A separator would be an indicator of an array.

For example:

> $.Colors[*].name

Would need to become:

```
Before: "$.Colors"
Separator: "[*]"
After: ".name"
```

In the event that there's multiple:

like:

```
$.Colors[*].Color[*].name
```

It would need to take the first:

```
Before: "$.Colors"
Separator: "[*]"
After: ".Color[*].name"
```

I also want this to work on filters:

```
$.Colors[?(@.type == 'Primary')].Color[*].name
```

It would split on that filter value.

```
Before: "$.Colors"
Separator: "[?(@.type == 'Primary')]"
After: ".Color[*].name"
```

My attempts have been fruitless thus far:

```
static private String regexString = "\\[\\*]|\\[\\?\\(.*\\)]";
static private Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regexString);
private boolean splittable;
private String pre;
private String post;
private String split;

PathSplitter(String path) {
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(path);
    if (!matcher.find()) {
        splittable = false;
    }
    else {
        splittable = true;
        split = matcher.group(0);
        //pre = matcher.group(1);
        //post = matcher.group(2);

    }
}
```

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regex you need is this for getting the expected matches as mentioned in your post,

```
(.*?)(\[[^[\]]*\])(.*)
```

Here,

- `(.*?)` - This part captures the `Before` part anything as less as possible before the separator pattern and captures the data in group1
- `(\[[^[\]]*\])` - This part captures the separator which starts with literal `[` followed by any character other than `[` and `]` zero or more followed by a closing `]`
- `(.*)` - Finally this captures the remaining of `After` part

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/9GiXNc/1)**

Java code,

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("$.Colors[*].name","$.Colors[*].Color[*].name","$.Colors[?(@.type == 'Primary')].Color[*].name");
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(.*?)(\\[[^\\[\\]]*\\])(.*)");

list.forEach(x -> {
    Matcher m = p.matcher(x);
    if (m.matches()) {
        System.out.println("For string: " + x);
        System.out.println("Before: "+ m.group(1));
        System.out.println("Separator: "+ m.group(2));
        System.out.println("After: "+ m.group(3));
        System.out.println();
    }
});
```

Prints the following like you expected,

```
For string: $.Colors[*].name
Before: $.Colors
Separator: [*]
After: .name

For string: $.Colors[*].Color[*].name
Before: $.Colors
Separator: [*]
After: .Color[*].name

For string: $.Colors[?(@.type == 'Primary')].Color[*].name
Before: $.Colors
Separator: [?(@.type == 'Primary')]
After: .Color[*].name
```